# Map image into matrix in R to 3d Print

Tags: r, 3d-printing

We have an image like this:
[image]

Where I have a skull, and the raw counts of how many bones were broken in each area of the skull.

I also have a 3d printer and can make things like this:

[image]

Which was made in R using a matrix and the r2stl package.

What I want to do is map the x's and y's of that skull into certain locations of a matrix so that I could add the raw counts to those cells and 3d print that skull in a way where each portion of the skull would be higher based on how many fractures were in that location.  Thoughts?  It didn't seem like an example where an example dataset would be useful, I apologize if I should have included that.

Comment: How is the original data given? is it an x-y scatter (locations of single fractures) or crude like the first image, i.e., polygons with x-y bounds and a z value?
Accordingly, should the printout be strait surfaces of polygons, sticks indicating fractures, or some kind of single smoothed surface?

Comment: The original data was simply from a single column (~3000 rows) with character values of "Mandibular", "Orbital", etc..

My thought process was:  image of skull-> matrix, change values of matrix to equal # of each fracture (as height).  Unless I am missing something obvious.

Comment: And I was thinking (as the image has color in correct areas) I could do something like:  everything blue (in the mandibular area) becomes ~1200ish, as that is about the number of mandibular fractures